# How to join multiple queries with different tables and different column name

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join multiple queries with different tables and column name, along with I need to display the count of duplicate fields as shown below.

The queries are: (`Proj_uid` is common in all the tables which I need to match)

```
select proj_name,Agency,District,Division,Proj_status from tempproj
```

Need to join 2 tables to get the result that is payment80 and payment20 which contains billtype column with duplicate values, I want to count those value too

```
SELECT      p.Proj_name,p.billtype, COUNT(1) as CNT
FROM        payment80 p where billtype='civil'
GROUP BY Proj_name, billtype
```

(This is by using single table but I want this result by joining both payment80 and payment20 tables)

```
SELECT      p.Proj_name,p.billtype, COUNT(1) as CNT
FROM        payment80 p where billtype='Electric'
GROUP BY Proj_name, billtype
```

(The billtype values I want to count and just display a number of duplicate records)

```
Proj_Name      billtype
------------------------
policegruha     civil
gruhayojna      Electric
policegruha     civil
dcoffice        civil
spoffice        Electric
dcoffice        civil
```

3) Select billtype from payment, here also I need count the duplicate values and display in billtype

Duplicate values will be in billtype which contains some thing like this:

[image: This image displays the data for third query]

Finally I want an output like this:

```
Proj_name      Agency District     Division  Projstatus Civilbilltype Electricbilltype
policegruha    kumar  chitradurga  davangere ongoing                3                1
gruhayojna     khan   ballary      ballary   completed              2                2
Atered         john   bangalore    bangalore ongoing                2                4
dcoffice       ravi   mangalore    mangalore ongoing                1                2
spoffice       mary   chitradurga  davangere completed              3                4
hostel         jack   ballary      ballary   completed              3                3
univercity     kumar  bangalore    bangalore ongoing                4                2
mess           Raj    mysore       mysore    ongoing                2                1
policestation  khan   mysore       mysore    ongoing                1                4
conferencehall Rosy   davangere davangere    ongoing                2                2
```

Comment: Please post your table structures for all the tables that need to be joined

Comment: Did you mean to link the same image twice?

Comment: till projstatus it is from tempproj table after that billtype column im joining from table payment80 and payment20 which results only one billtype which contains civil,Electrical bills . for each proj_name im having more then one billtype values some thing like this for proj_name : policegruha is having 3 civil and 1 Electric which i need to count and display in billtype , billtype for civil as civilbilltype and here i need to display only the count not indivisually civil,civil,civil 3 times only the count which is 3 i need to display this applies for both civilbilltype and Electricbilltype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining three separate tables. One is physical, `tempproj`, and the other two are virtual: they are aggregates.

This is the technique.

```
SELECT p.proj_name,p.Agency,p.District,p.Division,p.Proj_status,
       Civilbills.billcount as Civilbills, 
       Electribills.billcount as Electricbills
  FROM tempproj p
  LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT Proj_name, COUNT(*) as billcount
               FROM payment80
              where billtype='civil'
              GROUP BY Proj_name
            ) Civilbills ON Civilbills.Proj_name = p.proj_name 
  LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT Proj_name, COUNT(*) as billcount
               FROM payment80
              where billtype='Electric'
              GROUP BY Proj_name
            ) Electricbills ON Electricbills.Proj_name = p.proj_name
```

Your requirement includes two separate aggregates from the `payment80` table. The `LEFT JOIN`s prevent suppression of project rows that lack any bills of either category.

Comment: thank you so much @Ollie but im  getting an error as invalid object name 'tempproj'

Comment: Thank you so much sir  now it is working fine , problem with some column names that's it . thanks allot sir